# Table View edit add rows with modal view Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode

I am developing an app with a tab bar and drill down table views in Xcode.

I am intending to allow the user to add custom rows to the table and intending to do this through a modal view controller containing a text field.

I don't know how to get the data from the text field in the modal view to a new row in the table.
Can anyone point me to an example/tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a string variable in delegate class synthesis it and use it in modal view controller by storing text field value into it.Then use it where u require.

In delegate class.h

```
`@interface
```

{
NSString *str;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *str;
` 
In delegate class.m

```
@synthesize str;
```

after `@implementation class.m`

In other class take one delegate class object and then in viewDidLoad method you code as

```
obj = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and store value into str as

```
obj.str=@"ram";
```

Comment: Any example/tutorial of the code that inserts the string into the table row I am new to this

Comment: iOS Apprentice part 2 by Ray Wenderlich has the tutorial on how to implement this method I just found out, too long a method to post on this forum but thank you for the hint.

Comment: Is that similar to my hint or any other way.Just provide link of that example.

Comment: The tutorial needs to be purchased but here is the link [http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice] it is the checklist one that has the methods